# Proving that A is not equal to B

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A=B$ if and only if $A\subset B$ and $B\subset A$.

I want to prove that $A\not = B$. Well, I guess, it suffices to prove that either $A\not\subset B$ or $B\not\subset A$.

However, is there any sense in saying that $A\not= B$ if and only if $A\not\subset B$ and $B\not\subset A$, which would correspond to some strict form of the argument?

Also, are there any names for these kinds of proof (e.g. proof by bi-inclusion etc...)?

Comment: As @AsafKaragila points out, your suggestion is off the mark. But since equality of two sets means that they have the same elements, ordinarily you show that two sets are unequal by finding an element of one that’s not in the other.

Answer (score 2):

The negation of "$A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$" is "$A\nsubseteq B$ *or* $B\nsubseteq A$".

Consider $A\neq\varnothing$. Then $\varnothing\subsetneq A$. So what you are saying is certainly not true.

But indeed there is a "strong" sense in which we can talk about the case that $A\nsubseteq B$ and $B\nsubseteq A$, when we want to talk about sets which are incomparable by inclusion. This information can sometimes be useful when we want to construct certain objects from sets which are "sufficiently different" (and we will usually require even more, that $A\cap B$ - their common part - is small or negligible somehow).